# Edit installation path

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-store-apps

I want to install appx Package with $Add-AppxPackage, but I need to install the app on my 2nd HDD, so how to change installation path in PowerShell $Add-AppxPackage?

Comment: Please read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You couldn't change the install location during the add-appxpackage process, there is no optional parameter for changing the install location in the [Add-AppxPackage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/appx/add-appxpackage?view=win10-ps). You could see the same opinion in the thread:[Question on "Add-AppxPackage" powershell command](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/cdcffc5f-ad01-431c-a767-9acef8aaace9/question-on-quotaddappxpackagequot-powershell-command?forum=winserverpowershell)

However, you could try to change the app's install location after the app is installed.The steps for the Windows 10:Setting-->Apps-->Apps&features-->select your app-->Move-->Choose your 2nd Hdd.

Comment: I need to install app, but I don't have enough space on my SSD

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the default deployment location of `add-appxpackage` command is the same partition as the package location to deploy, but sometimes it can switch suddenly to C:\ where you might have no sufficient disk space, and you'll run into:

```
 HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESS DENIED)
```

At least in the old W10 builds, you could change the default location of deployed packages in Settings>System>Storage (it is dedicated for Store apps, but works for all deployed packages too).
Then also the mentioned error should be gone, but if it still happens, check if `WpSystem` and `WindowsApps` folders have ownership set to Everyone (or simply delete them if they're empty on your non C: partition).
In newer W10 builds, in case of this error, you might also need to turn on Developer Mode.

However, there's a possible workaround if you can't access Settings>System>Storage option (however, it might not always work - I'll explain it further).

You can use [Symlink Creator](https://github.com/amd989/Symlinker) in order to make a symlink of your package to your destined drive, so the file will be visible on another disk while being physically on another.

Then you simply start deployment from the other disk, and the package will be deployed on the same partition from which the package file was added with symlink, but after the first deployment, it might finish with files extracted in the WindowsApps on the same disk, but ending up with `0x80070005` error anyway. Then, when you uninstall the package from Windows settings finding the app name, it might no longer deploy to the same disk location. In such case, you're forced to change default deployment location in the system settings I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I just copied the files where i wanted them to be (not program files though, doesn't work) set-location "THE FILEPATH YOU TRANSFERRED TO"
And then run the Add-AppPackage command once you're in the directory

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).